# Type org.eclipse.equinox.p2.query.IQuery not accessible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2

I was working Eclipse RCP application and I was configuring p2 updates for it.

I came across [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_uipolicy.htm) example.

package org.eclipse.equinox.p2.examples.rcp.cloud.p2;

import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine.query.UserVisibleRootQuery;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.examples.rcp.cloud.Activator;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.query.QueryUtil;
import org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.Policy;
import org.eclipse.jface.preference.IPreferenceStore;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;

/**
 * CloudPolicy defines the RCP Cloud Example policies for the p2 UI. The policy
 * is registered as an OSGi service when the example bundle starts.
 * 
 * @since 3.5
 */
public class CloudPolicy extends Policy {

```
public void updateForPreferences() {
    IPreferenceStore prefs = Activator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();
    setRepositoriesVisible(prefs
            .getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.REPOSITORIES_VISIBLE));
    setRestartPolicy(prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.RESTART_POLICY));
    setShowLatestVersionsOnly(prefs
            .getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.SHOW_LATEST_VERSION_ONLY));
    setGroupByCategory(prefs
            .getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.AVAILABLE_GROUP_BY_CATEGORY));
    setShowDrilldownRequirements(prefs
            .getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.SHOW_DRILLDOWN_REQUIREMENTS));
    setFilterOnEnv(prefs.getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.FILTER_ON_ENV));
    setUpdateWizardStyle(prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.UPDATE_WIZARD_STYLE));
    int preferredWidth = prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.UPDATE_DETAILS_WIDTH);
    int preferredHeight = prefs.getInt(PreferenceConstants.UPDATE_DETAILS_HEIGHT);
    setUpdateDetailsPreferredSize(new Point(preferredWidth, preferredHeight));      

    if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.AVAILABLE_SHOW_ALL_BUNDLES))
        setVisibleAvailableIUQuery(QueryUtil.ALL_UNITS);
    else
        setVisibleAvailableIUQuery(QueryUtil.createIUGroupQuery());
    if (prefs.getBoolean(PreferenceConstants.INSTALLED_SHOW_ALL_BUNDLES))
        setVisibleAvailableIUQuery(QueryUtil.ALL_UNITS);
    else
        setVisibleAvailableIUQuery(new UserVisibleRootQuery());

    }
}
```

Here the type IQuery and QueryUtil are not accessible as I am not able to access the package org.eclipse.equinox.p2.query

I am using eclipse Indigo (3.7) and the dependencies I have added in my plug-in are:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine
```

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata` as dependency